# how to easily get a list of values from list of dictionaries in python?

Tags: python

here is the json: (FYI, the '0' to '2' is the index of the original pd.Series([1,1,1])

```
json1 = {
    'hi':[
      {'0':1},
      {'1':1},
      {'2':1}
   ]
}
```

I want to get `[1,1,1]` from json1.

I tried:

`records = [v for v in json1['hi']]`

```
emt=[]
for rec in records:
   for i in rec.keys():
      value = rec[i]
      emt.append(value)
```

is there a simple and easy way like one line of code to achieve it? Thanks

Comment: `[next(iter(d.values())) for d in json1["hi"]]`

Comment: Just because you can write something on one line doesn't mean you should

Comment: @OneCricketeer Agree but the question asked for one line.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason that `json1['hi']` is a list of single-item dictionaries instead of just a single dictionary?

Comment: @0x5453 Agree 100%. Lists of one-element dictonaries are generally not useful, and rather than working out how to extract the data from them, it would no doubt be more productive restructuring the data more sensibly. Unless it's from third-party code I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dict.values`:

```
list(map(next, map(iter, map(dict.values, json1['hi']))))
```

Although this will only work if there's one key in each dict. Otherwise you can use `itertools.chain`:

```
list(chain(*map(dict.values, json1['hi'])))
```

Answer (score 0):

`json1['hi']` returns a list

From that list, you have dictionaries.

In each dictionary, you want the first and only value, which can be done with `next(iter(iterable))`

```
[next(iter(x.values())) for x in json1['hi']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data type is inconvenient:

```
json1 = {
    'hi':[
      {'0':1},
      {'1':1},
      {'2':1}
   ]
}
```

then the code to extract the data you want will also be inconvenient:

```
[next(iter(d.values())) for d in json1["hi"]]
```

If your data type is convenient:

```
json1 = {
    'hi':{'0':1,
          '1':1,
          '2':1}
    }
```

then the code will also be convenient:

```
list(json1['hi'].values())
```

Moral of the story: use a dictionary, not a list of one-element dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Since you like short code:

```
[*map(lambda x: list(x.values())[0], json1['hi'])]
```

```
[1, 1, 1]
```